# Can you wet shim above a tub?

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, tiling, underlayment, shimming

Is it possible to wet shim around a newly installed tub to bring all the walls plum and flat before tiling? Using a foam waterproof backer board and want to make sure that I’m laying tile the correct way. It’s for an alcove tub in an older home and some of the 2x4 studs are a little wonky.

Comment: you can shim the backer board yes, if that's what you mean. not sure what "wet shim" is?

Comment: Yeah... [edit] to indicate what you mean by "wet shim". That's a new one on me.

Comment: to wet shim is mudding the studs before attaching the wallboard to fix level, plumb, etc. That's fine, since you're using a waterproof board that will keep the "load-bearing joint compound" from getting wet.